# what is the use of length optional parameter in endsWith() function?

Tags: javascript, string

In the JavaScript method `endsWith` what is the use of optional length parameter?

```js
str.endsWith(searchString[, length])
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith):

> If provided, it is used as the length of str. Defaults to str.length.

I still don't find any use of reason for this parameter. Is it used for increasing the efficiency of the search? What is the application in using this parameter?

Comment: The `length` parameter: If provided, it is used as the length of str. Defaults to str.length.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally use the length property to define a shorter length for the string you are searching, and then determine if the string you are looking for is at the end of that artificially shortened string.

So if you have a string, and you want to find out if the string you are looking for is at the end of the string, but only if the string you are searching were cut off at a particular index location of which you are aware. You can give the string you are searching that index by passing the method a new length for the string.

Let's take a look at the example using the length parameter that MDN provides in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
let str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.'

console.log(str.endsWith('to be', 19))  // true
```

So in this example, 19 is passed as the length, making it only analyze the string as if it had a length of 19, which would be up to the "e" in "to be", right before the second comma. So it is really only analyzing the string, `'To be, or not to be'` because those are the first 19 characters. Since the string does end with "to be" when the string is only analyzed up to the 19th index (exclusive), `true` is returned. If no length parameter had been passed, it would return `false`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine, you have formatted string

```
202001010000 start 00000001
202001131825   end 00000002
```

and you like to check right orientated substrings, like numbers, codes or any other strings, you could describe the length and just check against without getting a copy from the string.

You could check a longer string, if the part string ends with *searchString*.

It is basically a short form of

```
string.slice(0, length).endsWith(searchString)
```

```js
var string = 'abcfoobar';

console.log(string.slice(0, 6).endsWith('foo')); //  true
console.log(string.endsWith('foo', 6));          //  true
console.log(string.endsWith('foo'));             // false
```